# Would like to see an argument for reopening attached to reopen proposals

Tags: feature-request

I'm finding that it is often difficult for me to decide how to vote on reopen proposals. The problem is that, unlike close proposals, such proposals don't come with any argument on why the post should be reopened. I wish it were otherwise. Is there a way to petition the SE site developers to implement attaching a rationale to a reopen proposal?

Comment: Is it necessary to add a feature for this?  Why not simply ask people to post a comment explaining why they feel it should be reopened?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. How would I address the comment? One doesn't know who made the proposal.

Comment: I think you misunderstand (or I misunderstand you.)  Basically if I see a reopen vote, and there is no comment giving a reason, and I cannot see a clear reason (such as the question having been rewritten) I just ignore it.  So I would suggest people in general leave comments; I would not attempt to elicit a comment *after* the vote.

Comment: If you're referring to the reopen queue, a closed post goes in that queue automatically if it has been edited (even without a reopen vote).  Also, a lot of times, the lone reopen vote is from the OP themselves (users can vote to close/reopen _their own_ questions at 200ish rep instead of the 3k for _others'_ posts)

Comment: @rm-rf Right: it's a good idea to look for the re-editing indicator, then quickly check the editing markup to see what changed.  Then, if you're feeling generous, you can scan towards the end of the comment thread to look for reopening arguments. Absent either of those positive indications, you're in the situation described by Mr.Wizard and there's no apparent reason to vote to reopen.